# Using a sanitizer in angular2 form usefull?

Tags: forms, angular, client, sanitize, server-side-validation

Is a sanitizer needed when my Angular(2) app is only gathering form values?

I send those values to the server to validate it against my validation rules (no client validation desired) and if everything is valid and the user clicks on submit, I accept the form and redirect the user to a success page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which sanitizer are you talking about?

There is no need to sanitize the data before sending it to the back-end. Your logic will work without problemas...

Comment: I am talking about the caja sanitizer from google. (https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-caja/wikis/JsHtmlSanitizer.wiki)